# LDAP "admins" group lost write access

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap

I have an LDAP server running as a docker container (`bitnami/openldap`), with the `whirlybird/ldap-user-manager` PHP front end. The manager automatically sets up a group called "admins" that has admin access to crate and change users and groups. All good, but at some point, I lost the ability to do that. (No idea what I did). I can still log in as `cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com` to make changes, but that doesn't work with the slick web GUI.

I have:
`ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com` and under that I have `cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com`. This is the group that used to have access to create users and groups.

My users are under `ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com` and I have a user `cn=myname,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com`.

I'm still quite new at this, but I've at least figured out that I need to run ldapmodify as root with external authentication to make ACL changes. Can anybody help me out with how to give the admins group write access again? TIA!

What I tried: I tried using the PHP LDAP Admin interface, logged in as my user, to create a group. Expected to create a group. Instead, I got error 50, insufficient access.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know the answer to my question, but I figured out why I had lost write access. I had created a nonprivileged user to bind to the server so I didn't have to keep my admin password sitting on various containers. Since I was using that user to bind my front end, it didn't have write access. I switched back to binding with the admin user, and voila, I can write users and groups again.